# Logstash doesn't show up on the Kibana index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, istio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBGYn.png)I am trying to install the ELFK stack on my digital ocean kubernetes cluster but I don't see the logstash index if I do /_cat/indices/.
In the kibana dashboard I can only see metricbeat index pattern and the metrics about my kubernetes cluster. I can also see the logstash deployment on my cluster. Any idea how to configure the logstash to show it up on the Kibana index pattern list?

logstash-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    # all input will come from filebeat, no local logs
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }
      if [ClientHost] {
        geoip {
          source => "ClientHost"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
  type: ClusterIP
```

WOuld appreciate if I get some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

First, run your logstash with something like:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

When you make sure everything is ok along the way up to the point of output, add the index name to your Logstash:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
    index => "MyPreciousData"
  }
}
```

And don't forget to add some level of security there, user/pass, or API token, whatever you use there:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
    index => "MyPreciousData"
    api_key => "iAmThEApIKeY"
    ssl => true
  }
}
```

And make sure your user have privileges to create indexes.

Once you have your (autocreated) index in, go ahead to Stack Management -> Kibana -> Index Patterns & create one based on that index.

P.S. Next step would be not relying on index autocreation & data type/structure inference, but doing that explicitly

Comment: I don't see any relevance to Istio. Why did you use the Istio tag ?

Comment: Thank you @Yuri G . WIll try and confirm if it works.